# Customizing object preview in CLion debugger?

Tags: c++, debugging, clion

In python you can define a `__repr()__`  method in class, and have a convenient object representation
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4l21.png)

Is there a way to make the same thing for c++?

I didn't find any help in documentation for Clion, the only solution i found works for visual studio.

Comment: Assuming a GDB-based debugger, you're looking for "Pretty Printers". Amusingly, you'll probably write it in Python.

Comment: VS has a visualizer which can be customized. Natvis, if I recall.

Comment: What you are basically showing is a debugger that evaluates a function at debug time. You can define all sorts of functions within your classes as a pretty printer (mentioned by @user4581301) and then just call them when debugging. If you ever programmed in Java you'll see a method that all objects inherit named toString. The idea is the same.

Comment: I appreciate your responses, but the point I try to achieve is seeing object representation straight away, not doing any other actions(like unwrapping the object and seeing it's fields or calling functions)